# OWL query in JENA

Tags: sparql, jena, owl

[part of ontology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LevlZ.png)i have an owl file and i want to query it in jena.  i used of URL of my ontology and i want to use of object properties from my ontology for query. but give me nothing output.do i need to make html document from my ontology to can query it in jena?

```
// Create a new query
    String queryString = 
            "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>"+
            "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>"+
            "PREFIX base: <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/RailwaysSemantic.owl#>"+
            "PREFIX dp_ontology: <http://www.semanticweb.org/ameneh/ontologies/2020/1/dp_ontology#>"+
            "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> "+
            "SELECT ?design_patterns ?createObject   WHERE{ " + 
            "?design_patterns dp_ontology:concerned ?createObject. "+"}"; 
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
    // Execute the query and obtain results
    QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, m);
    try {
        ResultSet results = qe.execSelect();
        while (results.hasNext()) {
             ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
        }
         
    }finally {
        qe.close();
```

Comment: Without seeing the data nobody can tell you if your query matches the data ... I doubt that ?createObject is an owl:Class ?

Comment: createObject is an object property from my ontology

Comment: Ok, but why do you ask for owl:Class then? Please show the ontology or sample data

Comment: i add a photo from part of my ontology.and it was wrong to use of owl:class i edited my code.but still i get nothing output

Comment: honestly, I don't know which part of the data you expect to get by the SPARQL query. Your screenshot just shows schema axioms, your SPARQL query does search for instance data in your ontology. Does you ontology contain any data about individuals using the property `concerned`? I don't think so. As a hint, look at the RDF mapping of OWL axioms. Note, SPARQL is a query language for RDF, OWL axioms can be represented by a set of RDF triples, thus, you have to figure how whatever axiom you want to get parts of is represented in RDF